# Deploying haystack model/workflow

Tags: python, nlp, nlp-question-answering, haystack, algorithmia

I'm trying to deploy a haystack model for Question Answering for my application as a REST API /API. I want to query and get my answers directly and I need to do it soon so I'm finding a way to do it on [Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/). Any suggestions, tutorials, examples  or any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

For reference, [this](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/first-qa-system) could be an example model.

Comment: This sounds like some homework. What have you done? What did you test? It would be helpful for others to diagnose the problem.

Comment: No, it was for a hackathon I was participating in, and even after a lot of research I was unable to deploy it in time. But, now I am trying to deploy it using heroku as a REST api as haystack provides a built in rest api example (build using fastapi). 

I am still looking for a solution that uses algorithmia to deploy this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Alorithmia, but here's a simple option to deploy a Haystack service incl. a REST API on any standard machine (e.g. AWS EC2 instance):

```
# Clone haystack repo
git clone https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack.git
cd haystack
# Start (demo) containers
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
# Run a query
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/query' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "query": "Who is the father of Arya Stark?",
  "params": {}
  }'
```

This basically spins up:

1. Haystack REST API using this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/deepset/haystack-cpu)
2. Elasticsearch with some demo data (see comment in the [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) for how to replace this with an empty instance for your own data)
3. A simple streamlit-based UI (you can easily remove this from the docker-compose if you don't need it)

---

If you want to **customize the pipeline** being deployed in the API (e.g. change a  model):

- Edit the `pipelines.yaml` in your cloned repo (in `haystack/rest_api/pipeline/`)
- Mount this folder as a volume into the container by uncommenting [this part](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/965b9614dbe64276d7dad5d5f87b1165a6892507/docker-compose.yml#L10) in the docker-compose.yaml

If you want to deploy on a **GPU machine**, just execute instead:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-gpu.yml pull
docker-compose -f docker-compose-gpu.yml up
```

For more details, see the official documentation of the REST API [here](https://haystack.deepset.ai/overview/get-started).